# Items booking software with approval

Tags: reservation

I started looking for a software of any kind to be used in a **company** that lets users (**employees**) **book/reserve resources** (for example cars) and that could be configured to **require approval** from administrators.

The main features I'm looking for are:

- The possibility for administrators to **define a set of resources** (ex. Car_1, Car_2, etc.)
- The possibility for normal users to **request a reservation** for a specific resource (ex. I want to use Car_2 tomorrow from 8am to 10am)
- The request for reservation must be **approved** by an administrator to be valid

I found nothing on the web but one open source project called [Booked](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/). I'm looking for something very similar to that software, but I found it a little bit complex and "old style", I'm wondering if there is any paid alternative (event with monthly subscription).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe our booking tool Clustermarket would fit your needs - it is an online equipment booking system that has different roles with different accessibility levels and permissions. E.g. Instructors can have full access rights to one or multiple pieces of equipment, Students can only be allowed to see their own activities, bookings and projects etc. Admins can define booking rules and permissions for individual users as well as groups of users. If this sounds like something you are looking for please do check it out here: [https://www.clustermarket.com/. Hope this helps!